# How do I increment/decrement a character in Ruby for all possible values?

Tags: ruby

I have a string that is one character long and can be any possible character value:

```
irb(main):001:0> "\x0"
=> "\u0000"
```

I thought this might work:

```
irb(main):002:0> "\x0" += 1
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting $end
"\x0" += 1
        ^            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

But, as you can see, it didn't. How can I increment/decrement my character?

---

Edit:

Ruby doesn't seem to be set up to do this. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way. I want to manipulate raw data in terms of 8-bit chunks. How can I best accomplish that sort of operation?

Comment: Yeah you can't do +1,  it's next or succ.  or ! on variables.

Comment: Oh, I suppose I can't assign to a string literal (or whatever they call that in ruby)

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci actually that doesn't work either.

Comment: I think you're missing a basic understanding of objects. You can't use `+` or similar operators unless the object defines that use. String supports `+`, but as a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Depending on what the possible values are, you can use [`String#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-next):

```
"\x0".next
# => "\u0001"
```

Or, to update an existing value:

```
c = "\x0"
c.next!
```

This may well not be what you want:

```
"z".next
# => "aa"
```

The simplest way I can think of to increment a character's underlying codepoint is this:

```
c = 'z'
c = c.ord.next.chr
# => "{"
```

Decrementing is slightly more complicated:

```
c = (c.ord - 1).chr
# => "z"
```

In both cases there's the assumption that you won't step outside of `0..255`; you may need to add checks for that.

Comment: What about for all possible values? Is there a method which always increments the binary value of the character? If I started with `"\x0"` and called `#next` enough times I'd end up with `"z"` and then my next call to `#next` would give me `"aa"`. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Also, how do I decrement? And as a bonus, how might I increase or decrease the value by a certain number?

Comment: @anthropomorphic I've updated my answer.  Increasing or decreasing by a certain amount would be a simple variant on how I've demonstrated decrementing.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do:

```
"\x0" += 1
```

Because, in Ruby, that is short for:

```
"\x0" = "\x0" + 1
```

and it is a syntax error to assign a value to a string literal.

However, given an integer `n`, you can convert it to a character by using `pack`. For example,

```
[97].pack 'U' # => "a"
```

Similarly, you can convert a character into an integer by using `ord`. For example:

```
[300].pack('U').ord # => 300
```

With these methods, you can easily write your own increment function, as follows:

```
def step(c, delta=1)
  [c.ord + delta].pack 'U'
end

def increment(c)
  step c, 1
end

def decrement(c)
  step c, -1
end
```

If you just want to manipulate bytes, you can use [String#bytes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-bytes), which will give you an array of integers to play with. You can use [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) to convert those bytes back to a String. (Refer to documentation for encoding options.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`String#next`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String#next-instance_method) method.

Comment: Instead of a single sentence suggestion, you should add an example to show why this is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am a newbie yet. I will improve my responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant method (for alphanumeric chars) would be:

```
"a".tr('0-9a-z','1-9a-z0')
```

which would loop the a through to z and through the numbers and back to a.

I reread the question and see, that my answer has nothing to do with the question. I have no answer for manipulationg 8-bit values directly.