# Ruby converting letters in string to letters 13 places further in the alphabet

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to solve a problem where when given a string I convert each letter 13 places further in the alphabet. For example

```
a => n
b => o
c => p
```

Basically every letter in the string is converted 13 alphabet spaces.

If given the string 'sentence' i'd like it to convert to

```
'feagrapr'
```

I have no idea how to do it. I've tried

```
'sentence'.each_char.select{|x| 13.times{x.next}}
```

and I still couldn't solve it.

This one has been puzzling me for a while now, and I've given up trying to solve it.

I need your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From here -> [How do I increment/decrement a character in Ruby for all possible values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006598/how-do-i-increment-decrement-a-character-in-ruby-for-all-possible-values)

you should do it like:

```
def increment_char(char)
 return 'a' if char == 'z'
 char.ord.next.chr
end

def increment_by_13(str)
 conc = []
 tmp = ''
 str.split('').each do |c|
   tmp = c
   13.times.map{ |i| tmp = increment_char(tmp) }
   conc << tmp
 end
 conc
end
```

Or close.

Comment: Nice! Glad to help :)

Comment: Just `char.next` would do.

Comment: Actually, this is all really sloppy and non-idiomatic. Here's the entire body of the *single* function you need, get rid of `increment_char`. `def increment_by_13(str); 13.times { str = str.chars.map { |c| c == 'z' ? 'a' : c.next }.join; }; str; end`

Comment: Cool! So much better and clean. 
I was more worried with giving an answer than refactoring, but I should've done it. Glad you liked my 'base code' though :)

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, there is a better way to achieve the same in idiomatic Ruby:

```
def rot13(string)
  string.tr("A-Za-z", "N-ZA-Mn-za-m")
end
```

This works because the parameter 13 is hard-coded in the OP's question, in which case the `tr` function seems to be just the right tool for the job!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-tr) as TCSGrad suggests is the ideal solution.

Some alternatives:

#### Using `case`, `ord`, and `chr`

```
word = 'sentence'

word.gsub(/./) do |c|
  case c
  when 'a'..'m', 'A'..'M' then (c.ord + 13).chr
  when 'n'..'z', 'N'..'Z' then (c.ord - 13).chr
  else c
  end
end
```

#### Using `gsub` and a hash for multiple replacement

```
word = 'sentence'
from = [*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z']
to = [*'n'..'z', *'a'..'m', *'N'..'Z', *'A'..'M']
cipher = from.zip(to).to_h

word.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/, cipher)
```

Note, `Array#to_h` requires Ruby 2.1+. For older versions of Ruby, use

`cipher = Hash[from.zip(to)]`.

Comment: I like both solutions. In the first, you don't need `c =` and a variant would be to replace `chars.map` with `gsub(/./)`, in which case you would not need `join`.