# Rails before_create increment in alphabetical order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a field in my table - `exposure`. The name of the field is called `setup_code`, 
Every time an `exposure` is created, I want to increment `setup_code` from A-Z how can I achieve that?

Here's what I have done so far, according to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18006638/5012862) I saw that it is possible to increment using `next`

```
class Exposure < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :create_setup_code

  def create_setup_code
    last_setup_code = self.last.setup_code
    last_setup_code.next
  end
end
```

This approach will work if I already have at least one setup_code in the database, say setup_code = 'A', then for the next setup_code, it will be 'B' when `before_create` is called.

How do I initialize with the first `setup_code = 'A'`?

Comment: `last_setup_code = self.last.setup_code || 'A'`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra that will lead to a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'last_setup_code' for nil:NilClass`. `self.last` returns nil when when no records have been saved

Comment: I would also seriously consider if what you doing really is a good idea - this is really prone to race conditions. If two requests hit the server at the same time its possible that two records will be inserted with the same setup_code. I would consider using an auto-incrementing column and mapping the integer to a letter in the software which can be done with `('A'..'Z').to_a[x-1]`.

Comment: Wow, @max thanks for bringing this up. So what would be the complete reimplementation of my method using this approach? Can you please type that in an answer?

Comment: Done, I still don't understand the use case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a pretty cool way to do this in Postgres by applying a computed default value to the column.

First we want to define a Postgres function that gives you a letter given an integer (1 = A, 26 = Z) so that we can get a letter given an ID.

```
class CreateIdToLetterFunction < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION id_to_letter(integer) RETURNS varchar
      AS 'select chr(64 + $1)' 
      LANGUAGE SQL
      IMMUTABLE
      RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP FUNCTION id_to_letter(integer);
    SQL
  end
end
```

`chr(int)` returns the character with the given ASCII code. In ASCII A is at 65 so we need to pad the value with 64.

We then add function that counts the exposures so that we can use it the default:

```
class AddExposureCountFunction < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_exposures() RETURNS bigint
        AS 'select count(*) from exposures'
        LANGUAGE SQL
        VOLATILE;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP FUNCTION count_exposures();
    SQL
  end
end
```

We then want to alter the exposures.setup_code column to add a default value.

```
class AddDefaultSetupCodeToExposures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column_default(
      :exposures,
      :setup_code,
      from: nil,
      to: -> {"id_to_letter(CAST(count_exposures() AS integer) + 1)"}
    )
  end
end
```

We wrap the new default in a lambda (`->{}`) as this tells ActiveRecord that the value is not a literal value and should be added to the statement as SQL.

As this is handled on the DB level no additional model code is needed. Note that the caveat regarding default values set by the DB applies - the value will be nil until you reload the instance from the db.

### added

However if you want something functionally equal to the epically bad code from your comment you just need:

```
class Exposure < ApplicationRecord
  SETUP_CODES = %w{ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2 }
  def self.next_setup_code(current_code)
    if !SETUP_CODES.index(current_code) || current_code == SETUP_CODES.last
      "error"
    else
      SETUP_CODES[ SETUP_CODES.index(current_code) + 1 ]
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: If an insert was rolled back without being committed, the ID would skip a value wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, that is a potential bug @DavidAldridge.

Comment: I guess it could be solved  by using a function that returns (`SELECT count(*) FROM exposures` as the input instead of `currval('exposures_id_seq')`. Any thoughts @DavidAldridge?

Comment: Edited to use count query instead of the id as the input to avoid the rollback issue mentioned by @DavidAldridge.

Comment: Thank you very much max, so between this and the first answer which would u rather go for? I feel like this is more efficient and I have never seen anything like it.  But where does the `count_exposures()` function come from?

Comment: I would probably go for this solution as it does not involve any typecasting in rails.  The `count_exposures()` is a user defined function that is added in the `AddExposureCountFunction` migration. It just does a `SELECT count(*) FROM exposures` - but you need to wrap it in a function to be able to use it in a default in postgres.

Comment: This is how it was implemented in the app i'm working on. I'm only trying to make the code better - https://pastebin.com/1pc8Vq1q and the client also told me there's never been a time the setup_code went past 10.

Comment: Wow, thats a huge steaming pile of code to do something that can be done with a simple array.

Comment: lmao yea right, I would definitely go with the cleaner and more efficient explanation from your answer. I have learned so much from you today, thank you so much. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @max Well using `count(*)` would be vulnerable to race conditions. During two simultaneous inserts, neither can see the other until the other is committed.

Comment: Hi @max quick question, i'm trying to access this field created in the DB through an AJAX call, some options i tried didn't work:

`def setup_code
    read_attribute(:setup_code)
  end`

`def as_json(options)
    super(methods: %i[setup_code])
  end`

this still returns null for the setup code, any idea how to get the setup_code from db upon create?

Comment: Getting the setup_code from an existing record should not be any different than any other attribute - its just a plain old string column.

Comment: Yes thats right, but getting it upon create, returns null, u know like returning the value when the page is not yet reloaded, "AJAX behaviour" it does work however when the page is refreshed, but programmatically appending it to HTML node requires the returned object to be a json data, since it is created directly in DB, setup_code is not returned as part of the JSON data, hence the reason i wrote the 2 methods above, but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried calling .reload on the record? This will load the attributes from the DB.

Comment: I think this is kind of the expected behavior as only the id is actually returned from the insert query. If you want to get the database defaults you need to select the row.

Comment: hmm no, i didn't know there was a thing like that. when exactly is the right time to call .reload? on create? after_create?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187286/discussion-between-mayorsanmayor-and-max).

Comment: sorry to bother you. Seen an article how to use .reload, could show a demo how u would use this, just to make the attribute available in JSON object?

Comment: Did smething like this)) `before_validation :find_setup_code, on: :create` and then `def find_setup_code
    self.reload
  end`

and then this: 
`def exposure_setup_code
    self.setup_code
  end`

lastly this:

`def as_json(options)
    super(methods: %i[exposure_setup_code])
  end`

what do u think?

Comment: Well it’s not really a good solution since the before validation callback fires before the record is inserted. It look more what you want is a custom select query that returns the same value as the default. Can you write it up as a new question and link to it here?

Comment: Okay I'll do that.

Comment: Basically what you want to do is run that same snippet as the which creates default but as just a raw sql SELECT ... query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355381/how-to-get-the-value-from-postgres-computed-function-upon-object-creation-in-rai

Comment: BTW, [mayorsanmayor says "thanks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355381/how-to-get-the-value-from-postgres-computed-function-upon-object-creation-in-rai/54355728#comment95526888_543557280) again.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid race conditions you may want to use an auto-incrementing column.

First create a auto-incrementing column:

```
class AddSetupCodeToExposures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :exposures, :setup_code, :serial
  end
end
```

This example is for PostgreSQL. On MySQL you can only create a secondary auto-incrementing column if you are using MyISAM and not INNODB (why would you?) so you'll need to find another solution.

You could possibly use the ID column since its auto-incrementing anyways.

Mapping an integer to the letters of the alphabet is quite simple in Ruby:

```
irb(main):008:0> ALPHABET = ('A'..'Z').to_a.unshift(nil)
=> [nil, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
irb(main):009:0> ALPHABET[1]
=> "A"
irb(main):010:0> ALPHABET[26]
=> "Z"
```

In a model we could handle casting the values by using a custom setter and getter:

```
class Exposure < ApplicationRecord
  # This creates a array of the 24 ASCII letters A..Z
  # adding null to the beginning lets us treat it as a 1 indexed array
  ALPHABET = ('A'..'Z').to_a.unshift(nil)

  def setup_code
    # the default value here handles out of range values
    self.class.integer_to_letter(super || 0) || "default_value"
  end

  def setup_code=(value)
    super self.class.integer_to_letter(value)
  end

  def self.integer_to_letter(integer)
    ALPHABET[integer]
  end

  def self.letter_to_integer(letter)
    ALPHABET.index(letter)
  end
end
```

One gotcha with auto-incrementing columns and database defaults is that the column is not populated when the record is inserted:

```
irb(main):005:0> e = Exposure.create
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Exposure Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "exposures" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2018-09-27 12:26:24.672016"], ["updated_at", "2018-09-27 12:26:24.672016"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Exposure id: 3, created_at: "2018-09-27 12:26:24", updated_at: "2018-09-27 12:26:24", setup_code: nil>
irb(main):006:0> e.setup_code
=> "default_value"
irb(main):007:0> e.reload
  Exposure Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "exposures".* FROM "exposures" WHERE "exposures"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Exposure id: 3, created_at: "2018-09-27 12:26:24", updated_at: "2018-09-27 12:26:24", setup_code: 3>
irb(main):008:0> e.setup_code
=> "C"
```

As ActiveRecord only returns the `id` column when inserting.

### Changing an existing column to a serial

This does not really alter the column - instead using the old renaming trick to create a new column and move the old values to the new column.

```
# rename the old column
class RenameExposuresSequenceCode < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    rename_column :exposures, :setup_code, :old_setup_code
  end
end

# add the new column
class AddSequencedSetupCodeToExposures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :exposures, :setup_code, :serial
  end
end

# convert the existing values 
class ConvertOldSetupCodes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    Exposure.find_each do |e|
      converted_code = Exposure.letter_to_integer(e.old_setup_code)
      e.update_attribute(setup_code: converted_code) if converted_code
    end
  end

  def down
    Exposure.find_each do |e|
      converted_code = Exposure.integer_to_letter(e.setup_code)
      e.update_attribute(old_setup_code: converted_code) if converted_code
    end
  end
end

# remove the old column
class RemoveOldSetupCodeFromExposures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    remove_column :exposures, :old_setup_code, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, max, the range is never going to get past 26, most of the time it's just 10 records, so that's A-J, my only issue now is that we already have the column setup_code in the table, so how do we make it serial? We are using Postgres so all is good. We don't really care about holes created when records are deleted, we just want to increment the last alphabet.

Comment: @max Whats the purpose of auto-incrementing column in your case?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky to make the DB generate the sequence in order to avoid race conditions.

Comment: @mayorsanmayor edited with instructions for how to change the column to serial.

Comment: @MartinZinovsky the race condition could occur if another record was inserted between the `create_setup_code` callback firing and the record actually being inserted in the DB - the result would be two records with the same code. Might be somewhat unlikely but could happen.

Comment: @max So you generate integer value and then map it to char? Cool. But wouldnt serial integer value go out of range?

Comment: I also found out that we can use Transactions to avoid race conditions no? - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @MartinZinovsky All we just need to do is assign setup_code to exposures when created and make sure that different exposure have incremented alphabets from A-Z.

Comment: @max thank you very much for taking the time out to answer this question thoroughly. Can you please clarify, what is the meaning of `default_value` in this setup_code statement - self.class.integer_to_letter(super || 0) || "default_value" ?

Comment: `(super || 0)` just prevents an error if the value is nil. `|| "default_value"` just provides a default value in case the integer is out of range for example. You may want to add some more robust error handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Exposure < ApplicationRecord
  NO_FORMAT = "A"
  before_create :create_setup_code

  def next_setup_code
    (Exposure.count > 0 ? Exposure.last.setup_code : Exposure::NO_FORMAT).succ
  end

  def create_setup_code
    self.setup_code = next_setup_code
  end
end
```

You can create as many as you want.

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, Isn't it should be like `self.setup_code = next_setup_code` ? as next_setup_code is instance method in Exposure class?