# How to get the value from Postgres computed function upon object creation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

A few months ago, I asked a question on how to increment the value of a field in alphabetical order in before create.

After a few comments, we arrived at a very [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539898/5012862) I currently have the requirement to extend this solution now and return the object and display it on the same page upon creation. I need Ajax to do this.

The current problem is I have no idea how to attach the created setup_code to the JSON object that is returned upon creation.

I have tried the following:

`before_validation :find_setup_code, on: :create`

```
def find_setup_code
  self.reload
end

def exposure_setup_code
  self.setup_code
end

def as_json(options)
  super(methods: %i[exposure_setup_code])
end
```

The idea is to be able to have access to `data.exposure_setup_code` immediately the object is created without having to reload the page.

What is the right way to approach this?

Comment: It sounds like you are creating and saving the object immediately, correct? You need the code after the object is created, not before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you link to is using a PostgreSQL function to supply the default value for the column in question. That means that the default is be applied during the SQL INSERT which creates your model instance in the database; that happens after the ActiveRecord validations so `before_validation` is too soon, you want the reload the model immediately after you've created it.

I think you want to say:

```
after_create :reload # Make sure to load database-generated defaults.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, will this still work on edit and update?

Comment: The default value is only going to be applied during creation so updates don't apply (unless you're somehow getting ActiveRecord to `update table set column = default`).

Comment: thanks, it worked! reload is that method, I needed. didn't know it existed until max told me in the comment of the other question. thank you mu and thank you very much max if you get to read this.